# Why ngrx return 2 objects even if I add takeUntil and skipWhile?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

In my situation I should have just an array list with my publications. But I got 2 list, the first is empty and the second is my real list.

I don't use async in my html, it's just a ngfor I take from my subscribe.

In my ngOnInit :

```
this.publication$ = this.store$.pipe(
    skipWhile(val => val == null),
    select(PublicationFeatureStoreSelectors.selectAllPublicationFeatureItems),
    filter(value => value !== undefined),
);

this.publication$.subscribe(data => {
    takeUntil(this.ngDestroyed$),
        this.piins = data;
    this.publicationAppeared = data.map(a => a._id);
    this.checkIfLiked();
    console.log(data);
});
```

In my ngOnDestroy :

```
this.ngDestroyed$.next();
this.ngDestroyed$.complete();
```

My selector

```
export const selectAllPublicationsFeatureItems: (
  state: object
) => Publications[] = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectPublicationsFeatureState).selectAll;

export const selectPublicationsFeatureState: MemoizedSelector<
  object,
  State
> = createFeatureSelector<State>('publicationFeature');
```

This is my result :

```
[]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

This is in my reducer :

```
    case ActionTypes.GET_PUBLICATION_SUCCESS: {

       const myobject = featureAdapter.addAll(action.payload, {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
      });

      console.log(myobject); // the result is just below

      return myobject;
    }
```

Result of console.log :

```
{ids: Array(3), entities: {…}, isLoading: false, error: null}
entities: {5d0261c743d8c30793eb8d25: {…}, 5d01713c7f353a1a81349299: {…}, 5d0170a67f353a1a81349295: {…}}
error: null
ids: (3) ["5d0261c743d8c30793eb8d25", "5d01713c7f353a1a81349299", "5d0170a67f353a1a81349295"]
isLoading: false
__proto__: Object
```

The result it's exactly like that I got on reduxTool

If you have the solution to don't use and don't call the first array list thank you so much.

I almost have to use my method checkIfLiked() just one time

Comment: Can you please remove `takeUntil(this.ngDestroyed$)` from `subscribe()` and move it to after `filter` operator of `this.publication$` observable and then try? Also please let us know what type of `"PublicationFeatureStoreSelectors.selectAllPublicationFeatureItems"` data this selector returns.

Comment: try to use skip (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skip.html) that  will help you to ignore the first element, skipWhile is giving you the empty array because [] !== null , you can add this condition

Comment: @user2216584 Thank you, I did the update on the topic for my selector. But my first empty array it still here :/

Comment: An empty array is not null or undefined so it wouldnt be stopped by your condition. Is it possible that your selectAll return an empty array?

Comment: @ukn In my reducer I added a console.log. And is just got one object, but if you have a better way to check from the selector I'm gonna try it

Comment: What does your state looks like

Comment: @ukn thank you.   case `ActionTypes.GET_MY_PUBLICATION_SUCCESS: {
       const test = featureAdapter.addAll(action.payload, {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
      });
      console.log(state);

      return test;`
This is how i check, and the array is empty in the console.log.

Comment: The state should be an object, not an array. And can you add your state to your post. Its hard to help not knowing what is/should be in your store.

Comment: @ukn I did an update. So you can see it's not an array but an object, my fault. But the arrays inside it's empty

Comment: What are you trying to get from your state, I cant figure It out with the name of your selectors

Comment: @ukn  Thank you so much for your help. I did another update you can see more correctly

Comment: I don't think you added your selectors

Comment: @ukn Now you can see

Comment: Your reducer does not set your state, you should have something like publications: myObject and your selector is not selecting any property of your state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks [so familiar](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/88gniv/old_meme_format_timeless_javascript_quirks/)!

I'd suggest you to `tap(console.log)` debug your stream so you see what's going on there, something like:

```
this.publication$ = this.store$.pipe(
  tap(val => console.log('skipWhile', val, val == null)),
  skipWhile(val => val == null),
  select(PublicationFeatureStoreSelectors.selectAllPublicationFeatureItems),
  tap(value => console.log('filter', value, value !== undefined)),
  filter(value => value !== undefined),
);
```

And the output will be clear about which condition is passing and what's going wrong.
Good luck!